# cual es la diferencia entre una clase y una estructura

Tags: swift, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

puedo ver que en algunos lenguajes como swift existen ambas, sin embargo, no entiendo muy bien cual es la diferencia.

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje y se me hace muy importante aprender todo lo que tiene.

Answer (score 1):

*Esta es una pregunta que se pude responder con [RTFM](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)*, pero a manera de resumen podemos establecer algunas diferencias:

- Las `class` son `ReferenceType`, los `struct` son `ValueType`(mas info [aquí](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm))
- Los struct son almacenados en el Stack, las clases en el Heap, por lo que son bastante mas rápidos.
- Las `class` pueden ser Extendidas, los `struct` no.
- Los `struct` son mas comunmente usados para encapsular datos.
- Utilizar un `struct` fuera de su scope (pasandolo como parámetro por ejemplo) hace una copia del struct en el nuevo scope, en lugar de apuntar al `struct` ya creado.

**¿Cuándo usar una clase y cuando usar un struct?**

Esta pregunta es muy general, pero podemos decir que, si necesitas tu instancia fuera de su lugar su origen, entonces ***necesitas*** una `class` pues un `struct` no sirve para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto la clase como la estructura pueden hacer:

- Definir propiedades para almacenar valores
- Definir métodos para proporcionar funcionalidad
- Ser extendido
- Conforme a los protocolos
- Definir intializadores
- Definir subíndices para proporcionar acceso a sus variables

La clase solo puede hacer:

- Herencia
- Tipo de fundición
- Definir desinicializadores
- Permita el conteo de referencias para múltiples referencias.

---

Aquí hay un ejemplo con una `class`. Observe cómo cuando se cambia el nombre, la instancia a la que hacen referencia ambas variables se actualizan. `Juan` es ahora `Pedro`, en todas las partes que alguna vez se hizo referencia a `Juan`.

```
class AlgunaClass {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var aClass = AlgunaClass(name: "Juan")
var bClass = aClass // aClass y bClass //ahora hacen referencia a la misma instancia!
bClass.name = "Pedro"

println(aClass.name) // "Pedro"
println(bClass.name) // "Pedro"
```

Y ahora con un `struct` vemos que los valores se copian y cada variable mantiene su propio conjunto de valores. Cuando establecemos el nombre `Pedro`, la estructura `Juan` en `Struct` no se modifica.

```
struct AlgunaStruct {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var aStruct = AlgunaStruct(name: "Juan")
var bStruct = aStruct // ¡aStruct y bStruct son dos estructuras con el mismo valor!
bStruct.name = "Pedro"

println(aStruct.name) // "Juan"
println(bStruct.name) // "Pedro"
```

Entonces, para representar una entidad compleja con estado, una `class` es impresionante. Pero para los valores que son simplemente una medida o bits de datos relacionados, `struct` tiene más sentido para que pueda copiarlos fácilmente y calcular con ellos o modificar los valores sin temor a los efectos secundarios.

> Fuente SO: [structure vs class in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217586/8933039)